# Join table with MAX value from another

Tags: mysql, join

```
select * from order
-------------------
|orderID|productID|
-------------------
|  1    |  234    |
|  2    |  234    |
|  3    |  123    |
-------------------

select * from product_supplier
-------------------------------------------
|ID|supplierID|productID|cost_price|latest|
-------------------------------------------
|1 |  1       | 234     | 1.00     | 0    |
|2 |  1       | 234     | 0.50     | 1    |
|3 |  2       | 123     | 0.75     | 1    |
-------------------------------------------


desired result
------------------------------
|orderID|productID|cost_price|
------------------------------
| 1     | 234     | 1.00     |
| 2     | 234     | 1.00     |
| 3     | 123     | 0.75     |
------------------------------
```

I'm looking join the two tables above to get the `orderID`, `productID` and the largest `cost_price` for a given `productID`.

```
SELECT orderID, productID, cost_price 
FROM order LEFT JOIN product_supplier 
ON order.productID=product_supplier.productID AND MAX(cost_price);
```

gives `ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function`

How can i restrict the `join`ed table to one row per `order`, joined with the largest corresponding `cost_price` value in `product_supplier`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way of approaching this is to use a subquery to identify the products and their maximum prices from the `product_supplier` table, and then to join this subquery to `order` to get the result set you want.

```
SELECT t1.orderID,
       t1.productID,
       COALESCE(t2.cost_price, 0.0) AS cost_price  -- missing products will appear
FROM order t1                                      -- with a zero price
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT productID, MAX(cost_price) AS cost_price
    FROM product_supplier
    GROUP BY productID
) t2
    ON t1.productID  = t2.productID AND
       t1.cost_price = t2.cost_price
```

Comment: i've gone for the subquery method, there are some other things going on, not least taking the sum of the cost_prices and grouping by a date that isn't shown in the question but this has solved my problem. many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when you need to use **aggregate** you must use group by and in compare condtion use **Having**

```
 SELECT orderID, productID, MAX(cost_price)
 FROM order LEFT JOIN product_supplier 
 ON order.productID=product_supplier.productID having cost_price=MAX(cost_price) group by productID ;
```

Comment: This query has a problem because you are selecting `orderID` but it does not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause (and also isn't wrapped in an aggregate function).

Comment: Your query might run if MySQL's strict mode is turned off, but it is better not to rely on this.